# Optional environment variables in Spring app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

In my Spring Boot app's `application.properties` I have this definition:

```
someProp=${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE}
```

But this is an optional value only set in certain environments, I use it like this

```
@Value("${someProp:#{null}}")
private String someProp;
```

Surprisingly I get this error when the env. var doesn't exist
`Could not resolve placeholder 'SOME_ENV_VARIABLE' in string value "${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE}"`
I was expecting Spring to just set a blank value if not found in any `PropertySource`.

How to make it optional?

Comment: Try this : `@Value("${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE:#{null}}")`

Comment: @MouadELFakir thanks for your suggestion however I needed a way to do it in the properties file

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Provide a default value in the `application.properties`

```
someProp=${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE:#{null}}
```

When used like `@Value("${someProp})`, this will correctly evaluate to `null`. First, if `SOME_ENV_VARIABLE` is not found when `application.properties` is being processed, its value becomes the string literal "#{null}". Then, `@Value` evaluates `someProp` as a SpEL expression, which results in `null`. The actual value can be verified by looking at the property in the `Environment` bean.

This solution utilizes the default value syntax specified by the [`PlaceholderConfigurerSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.html) class

> Default property values can be defined globally for each configurer
>   instance via the properties property, or on a property-by-property
>   basis using the default value separator which is ":" by default and
>   customizable via setValueSeparator(String).

and [Spring SpEL expression templating](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-templating).

From Spring Boot docs on [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

> Finally, while you can write a SpEL expression in @Value, such
>   expressions are not processed from Application property files.

Comment: With String default values, this worked for me in application.properties
someProp=${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE:#{"default_value"}}

Comment: @MauricioID: this didn't work for me, I had to use `someProp=${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE:default_value}` for String values.

Comment: An empty string can be declared like this: `someProp=${SOME_ENV_VARIABLE:}`

Answer (score 29):

This work for me:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_IP:localhost}:3306/app
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:mylocaluser}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:localpass}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because this is probably interesting to others who come here, you can override any properties file w/ an env variable implicitly.  Let's say you have property.

`someapp.foo`

Then you can define an env variable `SOMEAPP_FOO` (capital letters and . -> _ ) and spring will implicitly set the property from the env. variable.

Described further here: https://hughesadam87.medium.com/how-to-override-spring-properties-with-env-vars-82ee1db2ae78