# Difference between System.getenv(/**vName**/) & Auto-wiring Environment and doing environment.getProperty("myProp");

Tags: java, spring

I understand that `System.getenv(/**vName**/)` gets the environment property attached with vName variable, but I am curious about can we use the below also to achieve the same result?

```
@Autowired
    private Environment environment;
environment.getProperty(/**vName**/);
```

Is there a difference? and when we should use which one?

**Code is working**

```
@Autowired
    private Environment env; <---**I am not sure how this env is getting used?**

    @Value("${someURLVriable}")
    String APIURLTest;

    @Bean(name = "restTemplate")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

        String env = System.getenv("environment");<--**eclipse giving warning here.**
        String baseURL = System.getenv("illustrationAPIURL");
        if (baseURL == null) {/** If baseURL comes null i.e it must be on local/test Env **/
            baseURL = APIURLTest;
            env = "DEV";
        }

        log.info("Environment loaded : {}.", env);
        log.info("loaded apiURL : {}.", baseURL);
        return builder.rootUri(baseURL).build();

    }
```

Comment: Seems you're missing a spring-related tag

Comment: are you pointing towards @Bean? Help me find the missing piece :)

Comment: I do not know if you can autowire the environment in Spring-boot, but you can use the [`@Value`-annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation). Or my favorite: [use `properties`- or `yml`-file in conjunction with environment varialbes and default values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581132/4216641)

Comment: @Turing85 Yes using exactly what you suggested, just looking for the differences between these two ways to achieve I believe the same output.

Comment: You shouldn't use either. _Even better_ than @Turing85's suggestion, use `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I agree for shallow hierachies. If you, however, have a somewhat deeper hierachy, this gets, for example, a pain to mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `System.getenv("XYZ")` you will just access environment variables of the operating system. If you use Spring's `Environment` abstractions, you'll be able to search for your property not only in the environment variables of the operationg system,but also at the following places:

> *Properties* play an important role in almost all applications, and may
>     originate from a variety of sources: properties files, JVM system properties, system
>     environment variables, JNDI, servlet context parameters, ad-hoc Properties objects,
>     Maps, and so on. The role of the environment object with relation to properties is to
>    provide the user with a convenient service interface for configuring property sources
>    and resolving properties from them. - JavaDoc of the Environment interface

So Spring will actually search for your requested property based on  the active profile of your running application and in much more place like e.g. JNDI or ServletContextParameters. If you don't need this extra *search* of Spring in multiple places and just inject an environment variable (**hint**: there is a difference between System properties `-DmyName=foo` and environment variables `FOO_BAR=duke`), then you can just use `System.getenv("XYZ")`

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the values using `Environment` and can read the env properties like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        logger.info("{}", env.getProperty("JAVA_HOME"));
        logger.info("{}", env.getProperty("app.name"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In below you will use properties file values, and will use properties values e.g.

application.properties

```
path: {HOME}/dir
```

and code for this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Value("${path}")
    private String path;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       logger.info("value from property is: {}", path));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Updated:** 
And, System.getEnv method you can use in simple Java class also not requirement of spring autowiring.

Comment: Yes, true. I want to know if there is a difference between the two methods.

Comment: Good Effort, but there are 3 diff thing. 1 Environement variable autowired 2. Sytem,getEnv 3.Sytem,getProp. You are describing 3rd one. I am looking for diff in first 2.

Comment: System.getEnv method you can use in simple Java class also not requirement of spring autowiring.

Comment: Exactly :) Update your answer and I will upvote as appreciation

Comment: @Rishi: Updated :)