# Injecting map of key->values (variableName->system environment value) from application.properties to map-object with default values

Tags: java, spring-boot

In `application.properties` I have map like:

```
variable.map={variableName1: '${VARIABLE_VALUE_1}', variableName2: '${VARIABLE_VALUE_2}'}
```

`VARIABLE_VALUE_1` and `VARIABLE_VALUE_2` comes from system environment variables.

I can read it in my configuration class very simple with SpEL:

```
@Value("#{${variable.map}}")
private Map<String,String> variableMap;
```

Thus, I am getting two entries of map `variableMap`. But if one of them doesn't exsist I am getting an exception when application started:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'VARIABLE_VALUE_1' in value "{variableName1: '${VARIABLE_VALUE_1}', variableName2: '${VARIABLE_VALUE_2}'}"
```

How can I handle this exception? For example by put `variableName1` with any default value or by putting only entry `variableName2 -> VARIABLE_VALUE_2` (so if system environment variable doesn't exsist -> ignore it) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional environment variables in Spring app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580247/optional-environment-variables-in-spring-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you use parameters in your value, it depends on them. So if you declare two parameters, you need both.

You could try to declare the whole map in one parameter, so you are more flexible (but I'm not sure if that works). And even if you don't have that parameter, you could declare to use null instead.

```
variable.map=${VARIABLE_VALUE:#{null}}
```

And declare your value as:

```
VARIABLE_VALUE = "{'variableName1': 'value1', 'variableName2': 'value2'}"
```