# using Environment variable in yml in combination with if expression

Tags: spring, yaml, expression

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
ENV_VAR may or may not be defined.
I would like 'time' to take a value depending on this variable. Can someone suggest me a proper solution? I tried this:

```
time: {{ 45000 if (${ENV_VAR} is not defined or ${ENV_VAR} == 'false') else 20000 }}
```

Comment: „*if expressions*“ are not a YAML feature. `{{ … }}` is not Spring syntax either. If you're using some templating engine, you need to tell us about it; we don't magically know and there are a lot of different templating engines used with YAML. Also please describe the error you're getting.

Comment: I saw examples on the internet. I didn't know about templating engines. Make sense now why this doesn't work. Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your actual question is probably „how to define a default value if some env var isn't set“ which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580247/optional-environment-variables-in-spring-app).